# Wordpress Default Directory Change

Tags: wordpress, security, hardening

I am trying to change the default path of the WP default directories such as `wp-content`, `wp-include` etc to avoid `wpscan`. 
I have tried using plugin would it possible to perform the same using manual techniques. I am using apache as a web server.

An example, I have tried:

```
RewriteRule ^cms_plugins/(.+) /wordpress/wp-content/plugins/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try the following steps to rename WP-Content Folder

1. Download the WP-Config.php file
2. Open and Edit the Wp-Config.php file to add the below line

   define( 'WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME', ‘new_directry_name’ );
3. Change 'new_directory_name' to the name you want for your content folder.
4. Upload WP-Config.php file back to your server

Follow these steps to replace the WP_Content folder

1. Download WP-Config.php file
2. Open and add the below lines

   define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', ‘new_directry_local_path’ );

   define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://new_directry_url' );
3. Change new_directory_local_path and http://new_directory_url to your local path and URL.
4. Upload back to your server

Comment: I have tried using the same but when I load the application it didn't load the theme. 
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/var/www/html/wp_folder/wp-content');
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://192.168.1.10/wp_folder/wp-content');

whereas my default directory is /var/www/html/wordpress/ I have uploaded the content in a different directory and gave the path. 
Can you please give more information. 
Thanks